# When can you use the average value of a function on $[a,b]$ for limits?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

My teacher has taught in class the following theorem, which I will write down, as I do not know the English name and don't want to create any confusion:

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R},\ f$ continuous. Then $\exists c\in\mathbb[a,b]$ such that $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = f(c)$.

He then proceeded with two exercises, one of which I did not understand.

> Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1(\sin x)^n dx$

Using the theorem above: $\exists c_n[0,1], \int_0^1(\sin x)^n dx = f(c_n) = (\sin c_n)^n \stackrel{n\to\infty}{===}0$. No questions here, everything works quite easily.

> Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 nx^n dx$

Using this problem, he tried to show that the theorem doesn't always work, but I didn't understand at all why. So, he first tried using the theorem:
$$\text{Let } g_n(x)=nx^n, \ g(x) \text{ continuous} \Rightarrow \exists c_n\in[0,1], \int_0^1 g_n(x) dx = g_n(c_n) = nc_n^n = \frac{n}{(\frac{1}{c_n})^n} \stackrel{\frac{\infty}{\infty}}{==} 0 \text{ (because the exponential function } \left(\frac{1}{c_n}\right)^n \text{ increase much faster)}$$
All right, everything seems correct from my point of view. However, he then tried to compute the integral as one would normally do: $$\int_0^1 nx^n dx = \frac{nx^{n+1}}{n+1}\Bigg\vert_0^1 = \frac{n}{n+1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow} 1$$

So, despite $g_n(x)$ checking every condition of the theorem, it does not seem to work in this case. All that being said, my questions are: why doesn't it work? How would I check beforehand that it doesn't work? What would be some other circumstances in which the theorem would "fail"?

Comment: I don't understand why the limit of $n\times c_n^{-n}$ is meant to be $0$.  $c_n$ could be $1$, yes?  Nothing in what you wrote prevents that. And, while you could argue that no particular $c_n$ could actually be $1$, what prevents $c_n\to 1$ in the limit?

Comment: Note:  that problem is present in your first example as well since, a priori, it could be be case that $\sin (c_n)=1$    In that case, however, $c_n$ is bounded away from $\frac {\pi}2$ so the issue can be avoided.  Still, this needs to be pointed out.

Comment: As an exercise, use these methods to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{.999}nx^n\,dx=0$.   Just to drive home the fact that it is the behavior near $1$ that matters here.

Comment: @lulu I think I understand what you mean. Please correct me if my conclusion is wrong: in order to be able to use that theorem to solve such exercises, I must first check that $\forall c\in[a,b]$, the limit of $f(c)$ exists and all the limits turn out to be the same value.  Otherwise, if there are, say, two limits, one for the upper half and a different one for the lower half of the interval, then one cannot choose the proper limit without additional conditions/information.

Comment: Sure, though I think it suffices to say that the limit must be the same regardless of the behavior of $c_n$ within the range.  If that condition fails, that doesn't prove that the underlying limit doesn't exist, it just means that this method is  unable to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "exponential" does not increase much faster than $n$ in the second example. The sequence $c_n$ depends on $n$, it is not constant. In fact, $(1/c_n)^n$ is equivalent to $n$, that's exactly what your computation shows.

There is nothing mysterious in what is going on and you can compute $c_n$ explicitly if needed. Here you have
$$
g_n(c_n) = \int_0^1 g_n(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 nx^n \, dx = {n \over n+1},
$$
which implies
$$
nc_n^n = {n \over n+1}, \quad c_n^n = {1 \over n+1}.
$$
This gives
$$c_n = (n+1)^{-1/n} = e^{-{\ln(n+1) \over n}}.$$

You can work backward to see that
$${n \over ({1\over c_n})^n } = {n \over c_n^{-n}} = nc_n^n = {n \over n+1} \rightarrow 1$$
and not 0. The error is to think that $(1/c_n)^n$ increases exponentially fast. This is true if the sequence $c_n$ is a constant less than one, this is false if it depends on $n$ and goes to one as n goes to infinity.